# How to read single precision float from binary file and convert to Erlang float?

Tags: floating-point, erlang

I have read 4 bytes (little endian) in a binary file using Erlang.

While trying to convert binary to float, I kept encountering error below:

```
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  list_to_integer/1
        called as list_to_integer([188,159,21,66])
```

It does not seem to be matching float pattern and end up calling list_to_integer instead. How do I get it to convert my single precision float to native Erlang float?

My Erlang function below:

```
readfloat(S, StartPos) ->
    io:format("Pos: ~w~n", [StartPos - 1]),
    case file:pread(S, StartPos - 1, 4) of
    eof ->
        ok;
    {ok, Data} ->
        % io:format("Wut: ~w~n", Data),
        N = binary_to_list(Data),
        case string:to_float(N) of
            {error,no_float} ->
                list_to_integer(N);
            {F,_Rest} ->
                F
        end

        % have tried this section as well, error too
        % N = binary_to_list(Data),
        % try list_to_float(N)
        % catch
            % error:badarg ->
                % list_to_integer(N)
        % end
    end.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`string:to_float` expects the argument to be a printed representation of the number, but in this case you have a binary representation.  You can convert it using a [bit syntax expression](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id82842).

```
> Y = <<188,159,21,66>>.
<<188,159,21,66>>
> <<Z:32/float-little>> = Y.
<<188,159,21,66>>
> Z.
37.40599060058594
```

That is, perform a pattern match against the binary, and extract a little-endian 32-bit float, and assign it to the variable `Z`.

NB: if you don't specify the endianness, Erlang defaults to big endian.  You can specify it explicitly as either `big`, `little` or `native`.

Answer (score 7):

If you know that the 4 bytes you just read are a binary representation of a single precision float (according to the IEEE 754), yo can convert it to a float using the definition given at [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format):

```
1> Float = fun(B) -> <<S:1,E:8,M:23>> = B,
1>     case {S,E,M} of
1>         {_,0,0} -> 0;   % you may make distinction between +0 and -0
1>         {1,255,0} -> minus_infinity;
1>         {0,255,0} -> infinity;
1>         {_,255,_} -> nan;
1>         {S,0,M} -> (1-2*S)*M/(1 bsl 149);   % denormalized number
1>         {S,E,M}  when E > 150 -> float((1-2*S)*(M+ (1 bsl 23)) * (1 bsl (E - 150)));
1>         {S,E,M} -> (1-2*S)*(M+ (1 bsl 23))/(1 bsl (150-E))
1>     end
1> end.    1>end.    #Fun<erl_eval.6.52032458>
2> Float(<<192,0,0,0>>).  
-2.0
3> Float(<<188,159,21,66>>).                                                
-0.019419316202402115
4> Float(<<194,237,64,0>>). 
-118.625
```

**[Edit]** as usual I am too late :o), and I didn't remember this syntax for binary match :  `<<Z:32/float>>` :o(

Comment: Perfect solution! Rarely where you can see a detailed binary math. Thank you.